# saving/restoring buffers not working in vim

Tags: vim

I'm using vim 7.2 in iterm2 (Snow Leopard). I'd like to save/restore buffers between vim sessions automatically, and added this line to my vimrc:

```
set viminfo+=%
```

Now, I open a couple of files and quit vim. I expect them to be there, but I get the home screen. This is the output of `:set viminfo`

```
viminfo='100,<50,s10,h,%
```

Am I missing any step here?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is reading `:help mksession`.

And the Vim Wiki(a) [has some tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_state_of_edited_files_when_reopened) to use it automatically.

Comment: Ok, so my understanding of this option is wrong I guess... What does % actually do? Sorry for dumb questions...

Comment: I'd recommend reading `:h 'viminfo'`, and in your particular case `:h viminfo-%`. Vim's online help is great.

Comment: I'll go through it again. But I found this plugin to be almost perfect to what I want to do. [link] (http://peterodding.com/code/vim/session/)

Comment: Then just stick with that :-)