# Save and Restore vim state

Tags: vim

How I can save the state of the vim after exit and then restore this state when I open it?

So it seems like it did not close vim.

Comment: To show the previously opened files?

Comment: this and the plugins' states For example, the filesystem tree of the NERDTree plugin, the current directory and last command of the vimshell plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving/restoring buffers not working in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055535/saving-restoring-buffers-not-working-in-vim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean vim session?

give it a shot on google, you got many articles about vim session.

like 
http://web.archive.org/web/20120118230658/http://vim.runpaint.org/editing/managing-sessions/

or in vim

:h session

Comment: I tried to use seesion, but it does not save the last opened files.

Comment: @itun files are reopened here. and in :h session, you can see "automatically loading the files you were last working on in that project."

Comment: Nice!  I didn't know about vim sessions.  This will be very useful!

Answer (score 29):

Use vim sessions, it's an awesome feature! (Adding basic usage here--Kent's answer points to these details.)

To save the current views+settings for your current editing session do:

```
:mksession path/to/my-session-file.vim
```

To open/restore the session do:

```
% vim -S path/to/my-session-file.vim
```

To overwrite previously saved session with the current one just add a !:

```
:mksession! path/to/my-session-file.vim
```